# EKS suddenly failing with disk pressure

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

We have an EKS cluster with two t3.small nodes with 20Gi of ephemeral storage. The cluster runs only two small Nodejs (node:12-alpine) applications for now.

This worked perfectly for a few weeks, and now suddenly we're getting disk pressure errors.

```
$ kubectl describe nodes
Name:               ip-192-168-101-158.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t3.small
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=ap-southeast-1
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-southeast-1a
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-192-168-101-158.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Sun, 31 Mar 2019 17:14:58 +0800
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      false
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  OutOfDisk        False   Sun, 12 May 2019 12:22:47 +0800   Sun, 31 Mar 2019 17:14:58 +0800   KubeletHasSufficientDisk     kubelet has sufficient disk space available
  MemoryPressure   False   Sun, 12 May 2019 12:22:47 +0800   Sun, 31 Mar 2019 17:14:58 +0800   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     True    Sun, 12 May 2019 12:22:47 +0800   Sun, 12 May 2019 06:51:38 +0800   KubeletHasDiskPressure       kubelet has disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Sun, 12 May 2019 12:22:47 +0800   Sun, 31 Mar 2019 17:14:58 +0800   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Sun, 12 May 2019 12:22:47 +0800   Sun, 31 Mar 2019 17:15:31 +0800   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:   192.168.101.158
  ExternalIP:   54.169.250.255
  InternalDNS:  ip-192-168-101-158.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
  ExternalDNS:  ec2-54-169-250-255.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
  Hostname:     ip-192-168-101-158.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
Capacity:
 attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
 cpu:                         2
 ephemeral-storage:           20959212Ki
 hugepages-1Gi:               0
 hugepages-2Mi:               0
 memory:                      2002320Ki
 pods:                        11
Allocatable:
 attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
 cpu:                         2
 ephemeral-storage:           19316009748
 hugepages-1Gi:               0
 hugepages-2Mi:               0
 memory:                      1899920Ki
 pods:                        11
System Info:
 Machine ID:                 ec2aa2ecfbbbdd798e2da086fc04afb6
 System UUID:                EC2AA2EC-FBBB-DD79-8E2D-A086FC04AFB6
 Boot ID:                    62c5eb9d-5f19-4558-8883-2da48ab1969c
 Kernel Version:             4.14.106-97.85.amzn2.x86_64
 OS Image:                   Amazon Linux 2
 Operating System:           linux
 Architecture:               amd64
 Container Runtime Version:  docker://18.6.1
 Kubelet Version:            v1.12.7
 Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.12.7
ProviderID:                  aws:///ap-southeast-1a/i-0a38342b60238d83e
Non-terminated Pods:         (0 in total)
  Namespace                  Name    CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                  ----    ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                    Requests  Limits
  --------                    --------  ------
  cpu                         0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  memory                      0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  ephemeral-storage           0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs  0         0
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age                    From                                                         Message
  ----     ------                ----                   ----                                                         -------
  Warning  ImageGCFailed         5m15s (x333 over 40h)  kubelet, ip-192-168-101-158.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  (combined from similar events): failed to garbage collect required amount of images. Wanted to free 1423169945 bytes, but freed 0 bytes
  Warning  EvictionThresholdMet  17s (x2809 over 3d4h)  kubelet, ip-192-168-101-158.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Attempting to reclaim ephemeral-storage


Name:               ip-192-168-197-198.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
Roles:              <none>
Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                    beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=t3.small
                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=ap-southeast-1
                    failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=ap-southeast-1c
                    kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-192-168-197-198.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
Annotations:        node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: true
CreationTimestamp:  Sun, 31 Mar 2019 17:15:02 +0800
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule
Unschedulable:      false
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  OutOfDisk        False   Sun, 12 May 2019 12:22:42 +0800   Thu, 09 May 2019 06:50:56 +0800   KubeletHasSufficientDisk     kubelet has sufficient disk space available
  MemoryPressure   False   Sun, 12 May 2019 12:22:42 +0800   Thu, 09 May 2019 06:50:56 +0800   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     True    Sun, 12 May 2019 12:22:42 +0800   Sat, 11 May 2019 21:53:44 +0800   KubeletHasDiskPressure       kubelet has disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Sun, 12 May 2019 12:22:42 +0800   Sun, 31 Mar 2019 17:15:02 +0800   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            True    Sun, 12 May 2019 12:22:42 +0800   Thu, 09 May 2019 06:50:56 +0800   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready status
Addresses:
  InternalIP:   192.168.197.198
  ExternalIP:   13.229.138.38
  InternalDNS:  ip-192-168-197-198.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
  ExternalDNS:  ec2-13-229-138-38.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
  Hostname:     ip-192-168-197-198.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
Capacity:
 attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
 cpu:                         2
 ephemeral-storage:           20959212Ki
 hugepages-1Gi:               0
 hugepages-2Mi:               0
 memory:                      2002320Ki
 pods:                        11
Allocatable:
 attachable-volumes-aws-ebs:  25
 cpu:                         2
 ephemeral-storage:           19316009748
 hugepages-1Gi:               0
 hugepages-2Mi:               0
 memory:                      1899920Ki
 pods:                        11
System Info:
 Machine ID:                 ec27ee0765e86a14ed63d771073e63fb
 System UUID:                EC27EE07-65E8-6A14-ED63-D771073E63FB
 Boot ID:                    7869a0ee-dc2f-4082-ae3f-42c5231ab0e3
 Kernel Version:             4.14.106-97.85.amzn2.x86_64
 OS Image:                   Amazon Linux 2
 Operating System:           linux
 Architecture:               amd64
 Container Runtime Version:  docker://18.6.1
 Kubelet Version:            v1.12.7
 Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.12.7
ProviderID:                  aws:///ap-southeast-1c/i-0bd4038f4dade284e
Non-terminated Pods:         (0 in total)
  Namespace                  Name    CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                  ----    ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                    Requests  Limits
  --------                    --------  ------
  cpu                         0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  memory                      0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  ephemeral-storage           0 (0%)    0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-aws-ebs  0         0
Events:
  Type     Reason                Age                      From                                                         Message
  ----     ------                ----                     ----                                                         -------
  Warning  EvictionThresholdMet  5m40s (x4865 over 3d5h)  kubelet, ip-192-168-197-198.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  Attempting to reclaim ephemeral-storage
  Warning  ImageGCFailed         31s (x451 over 45h)      kubelet, ip-192-168-197-198.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal  (combined from similar events): failed to garbage collect required amount of images. Wanted to free 4006422937 bytes, but freed 0 bytes
```

I'm not entirely sure how to debug this issue, but it feels like K8s is not able to delete old unused Docker images on the nodes. Anyway to verify this assumption? Any other thoughts?

Comment: I can't help with your question sorry, but I'm curious how you got ephemeral storage on t3.small instances? AWS says they're EBS only.

Comment: Have you tried using SSH to get on the worker nodes and drilling in to find what's taking up the disk space?

Comment: @Tim I'm actually not sure... I might have gotten the terminology mixed up. I have created standard instances using the CloudFormation template for EKS worker nodes.

Comment: @BelminFernandez good suggestion... will do that if the issue reoccurs. In the meantime I have terminated the nodes and recreated them using CloudFormation.

Answer (score 3):

This is my workaround:

```
kubectl drain --delete-local-data --ignore-daemonsets $NODE_NAME && kubectl uncordon $NODE_NAME
```

It drains all local-data & evicts all pods then re-runs all pods. But, I'm looking for root issue.

Comment: Did you ever find root issue? I am encountering this now. Seems like it might be docker images not being cleared. What version of K8s you have on the nodes?

Comment: same happening here with K8s 1.22, any updates?